# Differences between fsolve and solve/vpasolve

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I have to solve a non linear system of 2 equations with 2 unknowns in MATLAB. I used to solve systems using `vpasolve` but someone told me that this method wasn't very efficient, that I should not abuse of symbolic programming in MATLAB and that I should rather use `fsolve` instead. Does this hold true everytime? What are the differences between using `fsolve` and `vpasolve` in terms of precision and performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically that's the question when to use variable precision arithmetic (vpa) vs floating point arithmetic. Floating point arithmetic uses a constant precision, the most common type is a 64bit double which is supported by your cpu, thus it can be executed fast. When you need a higher precision than double offers you, you could switch to higher bit length, but this requires you to know which precision you need. `vpa` allows you to do this the other way round. Using `digits` you specify the precision of the result and the symbolic toolbox will do all intermediate steps with a sufficient precision.

An example where `fzero` produces a significant error:

```
f=@(x)log(log(log(exp(exp(exp(x+1))))))-exp(1)
vpasolve(f(sym('x')))
fsolve(f,0)
```